# In "Moontrap", what happened between the lines of "This is the way out" and "They never learn"?

Tags: moontrap

In the 1989 film, *[Moontrap](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097911/)*, when Colonel Grant and Mera are trapped within the alien spaceship, there's a scene where Colonel Grant grabs some cables, says something like "This is the way out", then they suddenly cut to them shooting the surgical robot again and he has a line of something like "They never learn". Was there a bit of cut film in between the scenes? Was this supposed to indicate that there was a second identical robot that suddenly showed up and they gunned it down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were some substantial differences between the US/UK released version and the French and German versions.  The US/UK version cut some scenes for ratings reasons.  Here is a [german website](http://www.schnittberichte.com/schnittbericht.php?ID=4950) which documents the differences in the two versions.  I can't seem to find something that fits the scene you are looking for, but I'm not that familiar with the movie and I don't speak German, so maybe something is there.

Also, [this forum](http://originaltrilogy.com/forum/topic.cfm/MOONTRAP-DVD-PROJECT/topic/10282/) has some discussion from a few years ago of people trying to put together an uncut version.  In it is this bit, which might help

> I'd definitely be interested in a Moontrap project.  The film's never gotten a decent uncut release, as far as I know - the R-rated US release is missing some dialogue scenes, the PG-rated UK version has had some violence and nudity cut out, and all international versions (e.g. the Japanese version that might be uncut) have hardcoded subs.

So, it seems there is some possibility the Japanese version has additional scenes as well.

Finally, have you checked out the 25th anniversary blu-ray release?  It has a full length commentary with the director and Tex Ragsdale, the screenwriter.  I haven't been able to find an online version of the screen play which might also contain the dialogue you are looking for (whether it was ever shot, who knows).

This probably doesn't directly answer your question, but maybe these are some leads you didn't already have.

Comment: I think the 25th anniversary version was the one I watched (it was a DVD I got from the library). Unfortunately, I returned it without checking the director's commentary. Maybe I'll try checking it out again and see if they say anything.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Ah.  Well, I don't have a specific reason to think the answer is in there, other than the screen writer might say something if a seen was cut that causes the dialogue to make no sense.  So, it's a long shot at best.

Comment: Yeah. I think it was just a bad case of cutting two clips together.

Comment: You've earned the bounty.

Comment: I am satisfied with the answer that the film was extensively recut, so this was likely just sloppy editing.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Sorry I couldn't find a more definitive answer.  You could also try looking on the screenwriter Tex Ragsdale's website http://www.ragsdalestudios.com/pages/jay-tex-ragsdale-studios-creative-director-writer.html.  At the very least he lists contact info... I doubt there is a flood of e-mails about Moontrap, so maybe he'd respond to an inquiry or a link to this question.

Answer (score 1):

i was just watching this Movie again since my "Childhood" XD,
and found this Thread. My english isn´t so well, German-Man writes English :P
"But i will give my best."

There are a line from Col. Grant : He said "We don´t buy /Shit,Crap/ (germans call it "Scheißdreck") from Machine." shorty after he beat the ...out of the surgical robot.

The same line said by Ray Tanner as he draw a cup of coffe out of this Coffeemaker on Earth Base.

"They never learn" .... he said after he Shoot the -Same- Robot again will be an 
confirmation/reminder, that he will not buy any crap from Robots.

IMHO that line his Friend said on Earth Base is missing in the US/UK version.

Hopefully this is THAT Answer :)

The German-Man

Comment: That's an interesting insight. So was there any dialogue between him stating the way out and then shooting the robot? Or was the line where he grabs the wires rendered as "We don't take crap from machines" in the German version?

Comment: He said "We don't take crap...." right after he hits the Robot, unties this hottie of Astronaut....they jumped in their Suits. The wires came down "Oh seem like a way out", suddendly a robot hand/grab appears and he shoot the mag. Theres no text line between the "crap" and the "they never learned" thing.  Thats the point who let me guess he means the "Crap" part ....on "They´ve never learned"          Let me know if you are satisfied now ;)